# Phonegap/Cordova BarcodeScanner cordova.plugins undefined

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Edit: What's with the down vote? My question was well-researched and I don't believe that I deserved it.

I know that there are several questions addressing `cordova.plugins` being undefined, but I've been unable to find a resolution with all my research.

I'm targeting only the Android platform.

I'm trying to use the phonegap barcodescanner plugin and am consistently running into errors trying to use it. I always get the error: `Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined`

Setup information:

- Phonegap version: `3.5.0-0.20.4`

  - Not using phonegap build
- Cordova version: `3.5.0-0.2.6`
- Installed plugin using all of the following methods (independently, of course, for testing)

  - Instructions here https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/master/src/android
  - `cordova plugins add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git`
  - `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git`
  - Also tried substituting `http://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner.git` for the wildabeast version

From what I can tell, the plugin installs correctly.

I've used 3 different methods to test what I'm doing: Browser (primarily Chrome), Ripple Chrome Extension, and the Phonegap Developer App. I get the error in the browser and Ripple, but nothing happens at all in the Phonegap Developer App.

The code is very simple.

The page it's being called from:

```
<div ng-controller="StorageMainCtrl">

  <p ng-click="doScan()">Scan!</p>

</div>
```

The controller code handling the scan:

```
$scope.doScan = function() {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function (result) {
      var s = "Result: " + result.text + "<br/>" +
        "Format: " + result.format + "<br/>" +
        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled;
        alert(s);
    },
    function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Why don't you test tour app un tour own device? I don't any of the places where you tested is supported

Comment: Neither of those will work as you have to have a physical camera on the device. For whatever reason cordova will not recognize a webcam as a camera on the computer. You have to test this plugin from an actual device. Additionally make sure you run `cordova build` after adding a plugin.

Comment: Also, the developer app does not support thirdparty plugins at this time. you have to deploy the actual app to the device

Comment: Ah, thank you. I will deploy it to my phone and hopefully that'll do the trick. That's a gotcha with that app that I hadn't heard of or run in to.

Comment: To whoever gave me the downvote: What gives? My question was well-researched and I don't believe that I deserved it.